# GSON how to skip serialization of specific default values?

Tags: java, json, gson

How can I get JSON to skip serialization of fields with *specific* default values? I can for example annotate the fields with a custom annotation for a `TypeAdapter` to parse, however I struggle finding out how to write such `TypeAdapter` without completely reinventing the wheel (i.e. I could skip the `write` method of `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` and write my own with reflection).

Background: I'm sending a GUI over Json, and I want to expand e.g. a panel widget with every possible property (background, border, etc.) but not send all of those as null values because most panels use default values anyway.

POJO:

```
public class LabelWidget {
    private final String label;
    @DefaultValue("c")  private final String align;
    @DefaultValue("12") private final String size;

    public LabelWidget(String label, String align, String size) {
        ...
    }

    public String getLabel() {return label;}
    public String getAlign() {return align==null||align.isEmpty() ? "c" : align;}
    public String getSize()  {return size==null||size.isEmpty() ? "12" : size;}
}
```

Objects:

```
a = new LabelWidget("foo", "c", "12");
b = new LabelWidget("bar", "l", "50%");
```

Wanted results:

```
{label:"foo"}
{label:"bar", align:"l", size:"50%"}
```

Comment: 'transient' keyword doesn't work? 'transient String dontSerialiseMe="default"';

Comment: Why not just assign the default values directly to the fields without any annotations, and not care if they are serialized to JSON? Too big JSON payload?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how @DefaultValue integrates with GSON but one of the solution that works is to actually nullify fields in case of default values during construction time e.g.:

```
public LabelWidget(String label, String align, String size) {
    this.label = label;
    this.align = StringUtils.isBlank(align) || "c".equals(align) ? null : align;
    this.size = StringUtils.isBlank(size) || "12".equals(size) ? null : size;
}
```

In such case your getters will return correct values and GSON will not serialize `null` values.

Comment: Except I already have `.serializeNulls()` in my `GsonBuilder` because of other 'required' fields that need to be serialized in other (non-GUI) messages. Are there any annotations or something to indicate which fields with value null should be serialized or skipped?

Comment: in that case you're screwed :) you can use transient if you want to exclude some values but they will be excluded always, or you must not serialize nulls - why do you care if the value is serialized or not?

Answer (score 0):

There are no options in Gson like that to accomplish your request and you still have to process such an annotation yourself. Ideally, it would be great if Gson could provide visiting `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory`, or probably enhance `ExclusionStrategy` in order to access fields values along with associated fields. However, none of those are available, but it's possible to take one of the following options:

- convert your value objects to `Map<String, Object>` instances (requires intermediate objects to be constructed; probably expensive);
- re-implement a `@DefaultValue`-aware `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` (I guess it's the best solution, but probably it could be even more generalized);
- temporarily strip the `@DefaultValue`-annotated fields from serialized objects and revert their state back once they are serialized (potentially unsafe and probably a performance hit);

  - clone values and stripping the values according to nulls so no worrying about reverting back (may be expensive too).

Option #3 can be implemented as follows:

```java
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface DefaultValue {

    String value() default "";

}
```

```java
final class DefaultValueTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory defaultValueTypeAdapterFactory = new DefaultValueTypeAdapterFactory();

    private DefaultValueTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getDefaultValueTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return defaultValueTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( DefaultValueTypeAdapter.hasDefaults(typeToken.getType()) ) {
            return new DefaultValueTypeAdapter<>(gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken));
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static final class DefaultValueTypeAdapter<T>
            extends TypeAdapter<T> {

        private final TypeAdapter<T> delegateAdapter;

        private DefaultValueTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<T> delegateAdapter) {
            this.delegateAdapter = delegateAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value)
                throws IOException {
            final Map<Field, Object> defaults = getDefaults(value);
            try {
                resetFields(value, defaults.keySet());
                delegateAdapter.write(out, value);
            } finally {
                setFields(value, defaults);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public T read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            final T value = delegateAdapter.read(in);
            trySetAnnotationDefaults(value);
            return value;
        }

        private static boolean hasDefaults(final Type type) {
            if ( !(type instanceof Class) ) {
                return false;
            }
            final Class<?> c = (Class<?>) type;
            return Stream.of(c.getDeclaredFields())
                    .flatMap(f -> Stream.of(f.getAnnotationsByType(DefaultValue.class)))
                    .findAny()
                    .isPresent();
        }

        private static Map<Field, Object> getDefaults(final Object o) {
            if ( o == null ) {
                return emptyMap();
            }
            final Class<?> c = o.getClass();
            final Map<Field, Object> map = Stream.of(c.getDeclaredFields())
                    .filter(f -> f.isAnnotationPresent(DefaultValue.class))
                    .filter(f -> !f.getType().isPrimitive()) // primitive fields cause ambiguities
                    .peek(f -> f.setAccessible(true))
                    .filter(f -> {
                        final String defaultValue = f.getAnnotation(DefaultValue.class).value();
                        final String comparedValue = ofNullable(getUnchecked(o, f)).map(Object::toString).orElse(null);
                        return defaultValue.equals(comparedValue);
                    })
                    .collect(toMap(identity(), f -> getUnchecked(o, f)));
            return unmodifiableMap(map);
        }

        private static void trySetAnnotationDefaults(final Object o) {
            if ( o == null ) {
                return;
            }
            final Class<?> c = o.getClass();
            Stream.of(c.getDeclaredFields())
                    .filter(f -> f.isAnnotationPresent(DefaultValue.class))
                    .forEach(f -> {
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        if ( getUnchecked(o, f) == null ) {
                            final String annotationValue = f.getAnnotation(DefaultValue.class).value();
                            setOrDefaultUnchecked(o, f, parseDefaultValue(f.getType(), annotationValue));
                        }
                    });
        }

        private static Object parseDefaultValue(final Class<?> type, final String rawValue) {
            if ( type == String.class ) {
                return rawValue;
            }
            if ( type == Boolean.class ) {
                return Boolean.valueOf(rawValue);
            }
            if ( type == Byte.class ) {
                return Byte.valueOf(rawValue);
            }
            if ( type == Short.class ) {
                return Short.valueOf(rawValue);
            }
            if ( type == Integer.class ) {
                return Integer.valueOf(rawValue);
            }
            if ( type == Long.class ) {
                return Long.valueOf(rawValue);
            }
            if ( type == Float.class ) {
                return Float.valueOf(rawValue);
            }
            if ( type == Double.class ) {
                return Double.valueOf(rawValue);
            }
            if ( type == Character.class ) {
                final int length = rawValue.length();
                if ( length != 1 ) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal raw value length: " + length + " for " + rawValue);
                }
                return rawValue.charAt(0);
            }
            throw new AssertionError(type);
        }

        private static void resetFields(final Object o, final Iterable<Field> fields) {
            fields.forEach(f -> setOrDefaultUnchecked(o, f, null));
        }

        private static void setFields(final Object o, final Map<Field, Object> defaults) {
            if ( o == null ) {
                return;
            }
            defaults.entrySet().forEach(e -> setOrDefaultUnchecked(o, e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
        }

        private static Object getUnchecked(final Object o, final Field field) {
            try {
                return field.get(o);
            } catch ( final IllegalAccessException ex ) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

        private static void setOrDefaultUnchecked(final Object o, final Field field, final Object value) {
            try {
                field.set(o, value);
            } catch ( final IllegalAccessException ex ) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

So:

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getDefaultValueTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();
final LabelWidget before = new LabelWidget("label", "c", "12");
out.println(before);
final String json = gson.toJson(before);
out.println(json);
final LabelWidget after = gson.fromJson(json, LabelWidget.class);
out.println(after);
```

> LabelWidget{label='label', align='c', size='12'}
>   {"label":"label"}
>   LabelWidget{label='label', align='c', size='12'}

Or you might also re-consider the design of your data transfer architecture, and probably proceed with just nulls (that however does not let distinguish between "really" `null` and something like `undefined`).

Comment: I didn't see this at first, but after trying your code, it seems like a complex version of pbielicki's answer (sets values to null and relies on the GSON object to skip nulls.)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus The difference is that you don't have to supply nulls when you work with these objects out of the serialization scope. In the code above the nullability is used only to serialize, and does not require your classes to provide special "default" methods. `@DefaultValue` is just enough then.

Comment: Indeed, makes stuff more developer-friendly. Btw, is it possible for null values to be skipped by default unless a custom TypeAdapter's write method overrules it?

Comment: @MarkJeronimus It looks like you don't have to build the `Gson` instance with `.serializeNulls()`, but annotate ignore-global-nullability-policy fields with `@JsonAdapter(value = FooTypeAdapter.class, nullSafe = false)` (the latter works even if no `serializeNulls()` was invoked, though). But, unfortunately, you cannot access bound fields in type adapters installed with that annotation.